# ssh connection with privatekey on apple

Tags: macos, authentication, vps, private-key

I am trying to connect to my VPS, but the problem is I recently bought a macbook and don't know how to setup a ssh connection with privatekey.ppk as authentication.

It worked before on my windows with putty, but apple has no putty?

Can someone explain me how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

In Mac computers you use ssh through the terminal. you'll need to generate an ssh key, and copy it to your VPS. you have two options to copy your ssh-key to the VPS - via `ssh-copy-id` command or manually.

this tutorial shows how to copy your key to the VPS - it's by Digital Ocean, so I recommend you to read and follow it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04.

Your relevent part is Part 4.

Comment: I already have the ssh key, I just need to know how to make my remote connection use it to authenticate